# Synchronized block not executed

Tags: java, applet, synchronized

I have Java Applet and I run file selection method from JavaScript.
Since security does not allow doing this I have a thread which monitors `boolean` flag

```
Thread uploadFilesThread = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (_UploadFilesSyncObj) {
                _UploadFilesSyncObj.wait();

                if (uploadFiles) {
                    uploadFiles = false;
                    ProcessFiles();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // TODO
    }
});
uploadFilesThread.start();
```

Inside this method I upload selected files. I want to have Cancel logic and after each uploaded file I check appropriate flag.

```
volatile boolean _CancelRequested = false;

for (JFileInfo fileEntry : _SelectedFilesList) {
    try {
        synchronized (_CancelSyncObj) {
            if (_CancelRequested) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "FOR Cancel Requested");
                break;
            }
        }
...
```

Method which sets flag is:

```
public void Cancel() {
    synchronized (_CancelSyncObj) {
        _CancelRequested = true;
    }
}
```

I know that method `Cancel` is called from javaScript for sure and if I put there notification window it will be shown. However cancel is not processed by "Uploader" thread and files uploading continues.
I've tried it without `volatile` and without `synchronized`, sometimes it can be processed but result is not stable (and it's correct as I understand without `volatile` and `synchronized`).

I'm new in Java and will appreciate any advice.

Comment: This seems like a far harder solution than using a blocking queue.

Comment: @AndyTurner I did this since I need only one action after flag is set, with collection I would be able to add in queue more than one job to process, but anyway this part works, and Cancel flag does not

Answer (score 0):

Use a semaphore instead of the volatile variable, and it will work reliably.

Here is the long story about volatiles: 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/index.html

Here is sample code for Semaphores: 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/semaphore-in-java/